# How stop zsh backspacing over trailing underscore in autocomplete filename?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have several files in my test directory that all start with 'test_'. I frequently use autocomplete to specify one of these files to edit or run. When I press tab to autocomplete, zsh correctly fills in 'test_' but then moves the cursor back one letter to between the 't' and '_'. I want to be able to type in the first distinguishing letter(s) of the file I want so I can press tab again to complete the full filename, but I have to press right arrow every time to get to where I can do that.

How do I get zsh to stop backspacing like that?

Comment: Please try if the behavior is the same when you start a ZSH session via `zsh -f`, i.e. without sourcing custom files.

Comment: It sounds like `zsh` is moving the cursor to the first ambiguous character. Perhaps test this behaviour in a new directory containing exactly two files: `test_a` and `test_b`, for example. If this doesn't solve it, I have the behaviour you're desiring - we can compare zsh options (or read the `man` pages ;)).

Comment: Apologies for a long delay responding, just got back from vacay :) I just tried and it does NOT happen when I start with `zsh -f`. It tab-completes to 'test' and then stops. What would that narrow it down to?

Comment: `zsh -f` starts a shell withOUT reading any of your configuration files. Everything is at default value. So this narrows down the problem to your configuration ;-) you either did something funny with completion styles or you are using *oh-my-zsh* (the later is an endless source of questions about broken default behavior).

Comment: I have nothing to add to @Francisco 's answer. Just start a clean ` zsh -f`, take your `~/.zshrc` and execute a line after another until the problem occurs. Especially lines with `compdef` (but you shouldn't use that as it is outdated) or `zstyle` are likely to mess something up. [Btw. to notify a user directly, you need to include @username in you comment -- it was just by chance I visited this page again.]